# How to get rid of unwanted bevel

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

I have generated this object in Geometry Nodes:
[image]
using this node setup:
[image]
The bevel is made in the shader editor using the bevel node as so:
[image]

I would like to get rid of the bevels that show as vertical lines on the front of the object but keep all other bevels where the columns of the object are separate from each other, ideally in Geo Nodes.

Thank you!

Comment: I added the tag Geometry nodes back in as the answer may very well be within Geometry Nodes rather than shading. Thank you.

Comment: For each edge you could find another edge living at the same XY but belonging to the other vertical bar, then store its height. Using this information in shader you could control the bevel.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your input. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can use such a simple crutch:

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't really mask the bevel, it just decreases it until it's no longer visible in the unwanted places (it's an equivalent of dragging the right slider of the ColorRamp in the question)

Comment: Hi and thank you very much! This will do the trick.